# How to break recursive calls between procedures on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 procedures: `A` and `B`.

`A` calls `B` and `B` calls `A`. I need to block calling if the procedure is already called from another one. How to check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) are global to your session.

So you could set a variable to TRUE in procedure A and then check it in procedure B.

Procedure A:

```
BEGIN
  IF NOT @called = 1 THEN
    SET @called := 1;
    CALL B();
    SET @called := NULL;
  END IF;
END
```

Procedure B:

```
BEGIN
  IF NOT @called = 1 THEN
    SET @called := 1;
    CALL A();
    SET @called := NULL;
  END IF;
END
```

These variables are global to the session, that is each session gets its own version of the variable.  So you don't have a problem if multiple user sessions are calling procedures.

But you do have a problem that a user-defined variable persists until the end of the current session.  That's why I show setting the variable to NULL after the call to the other proc.  However, if the proc is interrupted before setting the variable to NULL, you could get some wrong results the next time you try calling a proc.

Answer (score 0):

as variant you may check some value from table IsExecFromA. And Check this in proc B. If IsExecFromA = true then not exec again proc A etc. u?

Comment: if many users works then save in table field username (or him ID, or session ID): and in proc B check If IsExecFromA = true and UserName = 'Ivan' then ..

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following method:

```
create procedure A()
begin
  call B();
  call A_Code();
end

create procedure A_Code()
begin
  ...code...
end

create procedure B()
begin
  ...code...
  call A_Code();
end
```